# compiling parts of modules (without headers)

Tags: c++, language-agnostic, module

This question is referring to the "Modules in C++" proposals floating around, and more broadly to C like languages that need a similar feature (like my toy language I'm currently... toying with). In my world, "header files" do not exist, forward declarations would be a pest to maintain when writing any kind of code, and a single module can consist of several source files.

The problem is as follows:

> Source file A uses a function or class from source file B, in the same module currently being compiled.

Why is this a problem?

- There is no module file for the things contained in file B, it will be generated when all source files are compiled.
- I do not want to compile file B twice, nor force all files in a module to be compiled at the same time. This is to keep the eventual build simple and easy.
- I do not want the user to be forced to compile file B first. I'm not saying cyclic dependencies should be allowed, I just want to be able to compile both files in parallel. Heck, automatic determination of the necessary compile order would imply compiling files more than once, which is something I'd like to avoid at all costs.

Any thoughts and of course solutions are very welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for; are you looking for suggestions on how the compiler for your toy language should work?

Comment: He's asking the question in a rather language-agnostic fashion, as in "How is this *kind* of problem solved in other languages"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes, more importantly a general algorithm or steps that can be applied to resolve this. IMHO, C++ can't dump `#include` as long as this isn't resolved.

Comment: What about the other half of the problem: '_Source file A uses a function or class from source file B, which is not in the same module as the one currently being compiled_'? There has to be a mechanism to identify where the information needed by the current TU (translation unit) is available, and it probably should not require that all the other source code making up the other TUs is processed as otherwise you lose 'separate compilation' as we know it. You probably end up with some file that defines the interface (a header), and some mechanism that knows or is told which interfaces are needed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler a different module is like a different library, that can be compiled before source code using it. That info will be extracted from the compiled module containing everything source code using the library needs.

Comment: Controlled replication of information has benefits too.  Specifically, you get cross-checking when you change the implementation without intending to change the interface, or when you intend to change the interface but don't change the implementation.  Look at Ada.

Comment: Well, the obvious solution would be training the compiler at clairvoyance. If, to compile A, you need info from B, and you are not allowed to look at B, you can only try to divine it out.

Comment: The other obvious solution is to get rid of files altogether. A module source is stored in a database. Each named entity is stored as a separate record. The interface can be queried separately ftlrom the implementation.

Comment: While all the files are being compiled just once, it's likely they are compiled in several steps, one step being building a list of what is declared in every file. Another way is like Java: compiling on demand. If class A needs class B and you compile A but B is not compiled, then compile B. Note that Java requires an equivalence between class and file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgetting cycles...  (which is the part I like thinking about most):

Automatic determination of the necessary compile order DOES NOT imply compiling files more than once.

All it requires is detecting if the file B that A depends on has (a) already been compiled, or (b) is in the process of being compiled, or (c) has not started being compiled yet.  And I suppose (d) you might not have planned to compile B at all.

If (a), fine, no problemo.

If any other case, the compilation of A must be suspended until the compilation of B has been completed.  That's all.

I assume that you have some sort of parallel job manager or scheduler.  If (d), you tell the job manager to schedule the compilation of B.  If (c), you tell it to make the compilation of B higher priority than it already is.  If (b), you just wait under the compilation of B that is already under way is done, and/or suspend the compilation of A, possibly switch to doing something else, until the compilation of B is finished.

If you don't have a sophisticated job manager, possibly just make -j 8, you might get into deadlock, because all of your 8 parallel jobs might be waiting on some dependent.  In which case you might have to stop one of them, and latyer restart it completely.

But if you have a job manager that supports putting any number if jobs to sleep, then you do not need to compile twice. (Barring cycles, which require relaxation.)

---

I'm tempted to suggest that you remember the dependency graph from one compile to the next recompile.  That would be a good heuristic.  And simple not-quite-full compilation stuff like scanning for #includes might help get the right order.  But you might regard that as against the spirit.

Answer (score 0):

I would compile file `A` in a manner that it has certain expectations of file `B`.  If file `A` uses a function `neatofunction` that is passed an `int`, `char*` and `std::string`, and the result is stored in a `short`, then it notes that during the *linking* phase there must be a function somewhere called `neatofunction` who's three parameters are *convertable from* `int`, `char*`, and `std::string`, who's return type is *convertable to* a `short`.

If it uses a class `vector<int>`, then it notes that somewhere there must be a class named `vector` who's only non-default template parameter is a type satisfied by an `int`, who must have a default constructor (if you default construct it), destructor, and whatever members you use (assignment, `begin`, `end`, etc).

This delays a lot of (what are in C++) compiler errors to the link stage (and makes the link stage far trickier), but allows portable compilation. (And exported templates!)  I'd imagine this is all *much* easier said than done however.